# How to pass a variable to SQL query on AppMaker?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-app-maker

I have to query some data from BigQuery. The code looks like this:

```
function GetQuery(employeeId) {
 var projectId = 'xxxx-xx-xxx';
   var request = {
     query: 'SELECT HOD_Email ' +
            'FROM [xxxx-xx-xxx.table_name.dataset] ' +
            'WHERE EmployeeId = employeeId'
   };
 }
```

And I don't think it works

Comment: have you tried something like `'WHERE EmployeeId = ' + employeeId` instead of `'WHERE EmployeeId = employeeId'` or whatever way appmaker script does concatenation of string and number. Cauze right now your WHERE clause is not getting actua  value of employeId and rather looks literally as `'WHERE EmployeeId = employeeId'` thus always returns TRUE which ends up with returning emails for all employees in that table

Comment: yup but still cannot, GoogleJsonResponseException: Field 'undefined' not found in table ..

Comment: you need to make sure you actually passing employeeId to your function! Right? otherwise it is not defined. Btw, what data type your employeeId field - is it string or int?

Comment: now that I have passed the variable, but instead of employeeid I use the employee_name that is a String but this error came out GoogleJsonResponseException: Encountered " <ID> "Alif "" at line 1, column 92. Was expecting: <EOF> at runQuery (BigQuery:18)

Comment: if you are passing string  - you should add quotes - `'WHERE EmployeeId = "' + employeeId + '"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
'WHERE EmployeeId = employeeId'
```

try

```
'WHERE EmployeeId = "' + employeeId + '"'
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that works, but how do I get the query result? it does not work when I console.log(request) ..

Comment: one question at a time. If you have new question  - please post it as a new question  - but please provide specific details - the details of this (current ) question not enough to answer that new one